# Python Dash - Right Align First 3 Columns of Table?

Tags: python, html, css, plotly-dash

I have a table in my dash app defined as the snippet below. After researching how to right align first 3 columns while the others remain align centered, I am stuck. I see that in pure html/css the pseudo classes nth child can be used. But I read somewhere this is not supported in dash. I also tried doing it and surely I couldn't figure it out.

Does anyone know how I can have columns 1,2,3 be right aligned, and the others centered? I see also that there are "row-index", is there such a thing as "column-index"?

Thanks!

```
html.Div([
    dcc.Loading(dash_table.DataTable(
    id='my_table',
    sort_action='native',
    columns= None,
    data= None,
    page_current= 0,
    page_size= 40,
    style_data_conditional=[
        {
            'if': {'row_index': 'odd'},
            'backgroundColor': 'rgb(220, 220, 220)',
        }
    ],    
    style_header={
        'backgroundColor': '#f6f6f6',
        'color': '#303030',
        'fontWeight': 'bold',
  #      'text-align': 'center',
        'vertical-align': 'middle',
        'text-decoration':'underline',
        'font-family':'Open-Sans',
        'font-size': '14px'
    },
    style_data={
        'backgroundColor': '#f6f6f6',
        'color': '#303030',
   #     'text-align': 'center',
        'vertical-align': 'middle',
        'font-family':'Open-Sans',
        'font-size': '12px'
    },
    style_table={'overflowX': 'scroll'},
    ))]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use style_cell to set the textAlign to center for all columns. You can then use style_cell_conditional to overwrite the textAlign for specific columns using their column_ids. I have demonstrated this using the example from the dash datatable documentation (https://dash.plotly.com/datatable/style):

```
from dash import Dash, dash_table
import pandas as pd
from collections import OrderedDict

data = OrderedDict(
    [
        ("Date", ["2015-01-01", "2015-10-24", "2016-05-10", "2017-01-10", "2018-05-10", "2018-08-15"]),
        ("Region", ["Montreal", "Toronto", "New York City", "Miami", "San Francisco", "London"]),
        ("Temperature", [1, -20, 3.512, 4, 10423, -441.2]),
        ("Humidity", [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60]),
        ("Pressure", [2, 10924, 3912, -10, 3591.2, 15]),
    ]
)

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

app = Dash(__name__)

app.layout = dash_table.DataTable(
    data=df.to_dict('records'),
    columns=[{'id': c, 'name': c} for c in df.columns],
    style_cell={'textAlign': 'center'},
    style_cell_conditional=[
        {'if': {'column_id': 'Date'},
         'textAlign': 'right'},
        {'if': {'column_id': 'Region'},
         'textAlign': 'right'},
        {'if': {'column_id': 'Temperature'},
         'textAlign': 'right'},
    ]
)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```